# How can i import my own modules from DAG airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to airflow and would appreciate your help:
My project looks like this:
--AIRFLOWHOME
----dags
------my_dag.py
------labs
--------_*init*_.py
--------db_connections.py

In the file my_dag.py I'm trying import my module like this:

from labs import db_connection

It looks fine but when I try to run the following command
airflow dags list-import-errors
I get an error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'db_connection' from 'labs'

my airflow is not installed on Docker

what is my worng?

I tried to do this,
sys.path.append('C:\Users\xxxx\AIRFLOWHOME\dags\labs')
but it didn't help

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow allows you to use your own Python modules in the DAG and in the Airflow configuration. The following article will describe how you can create your own module so that Airflow can load it correctly, as well as diagnose problems when modules are not loaded properly.

Often you want to use your own python code in your Airflow deployment, for example common code, libraries, you might want to generate DAGs using shared python code and have several DAG python files.

You can do it in one of those ways:

add your modules to one of the folders that Airflow automatically adds to PYTHONPATH

add extra folders where you keep your code to PYTHONPATH

package your code into a Python package and install it together with Airflow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).